# Can't enable bluetooth on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I can not enable bluetooth using the bluetooth preference window. Moving the switch to 'I' will put it back to 'O', I can only enable it from the bluetooth applet.

Also, I have a bluetooth mouse and I would like bluetooth to be enabled by default at startup, I must reenable it again each time I boot. How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable bluetooth on every startup you need to add your custom command in `etc/rc.local`

- Open terminal and type

  `gksudo  gedit /etc/rc.local`
- Now add the following line before **exit 0**

  `rfkill unblock bluetooth`

You can also add the above command in **Startup Applications**

- Open Startup Applications from the Dash.
- Click on the add buttton.
  In the command box add `rfkill unblock bluetooth`
- Name it whatever you want and save it.

It will start bluetooth on every startup.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I hope next release will have this fixed so I do not have to edit a file by hand :-).

Comment: doesn't work at all